# sequelize : how to create constraint name

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a sql query with the following line

```
CONSTRAINT `some_key_1` FOREIGN KEY (`another_table_uuid`) REFERENCES `another_table` (`uuid`),
  CONSTRAINT `some_key_2` FOREIGN KEY (`another_table_uuid`) REFERENCES `another_table` (`uuid`)
```

I have created a associations in sequelize like this:

```
current_table.associate = models => {

    current_table.belongsTo(models.another_table, {
        foreignKey: "another_table_uuid",
        targetKey: "uuid",
    });
    current_table.belongsTo(models.another_table, {
        foreignKey: "another_table_uuid",
        targetKey: "uuid",
    });
```

});

but how do I add constraint name here

Also this line in mysql:

KEY `somekey_name_UUID` (`some_table_uuid`)

how do I change it to sequelize.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late by more than 3 years, started to learn about sequelize and just happen to get this same problem (not a problem at all, but it kinda annoys me).

As far as I know there is no property to add a custom name to a foreign key those are defined by sequelize, however you can manage to add a name by using the query interface of the sequelize instance.

Adding foreign key through model (foreign key name define by sequelize):

```
users.init(
  {
    user_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
    username: { type: DataTypes.STRING(20) },
    user_rol: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,

      //Adding foreign key -> generates CONSTRAINT modelName_magicString_NUMBER
      references: {
        model: "rols",
        key: "rol_id",
      },
      onDelete: "RESTRICT",
      onUpdate: "CASCADE",
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "users",
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
  }
);
```

Adding foreign key through queryInterface (custom foreign key name):

```
sequelize.getQueryInterface().addConstraint("users", {
  type: "FOREIGN KEY",
  fields: ["user_rol"],
  name: "fk_user_rol", // Custom name -> generate CONSTRAINT fk_user_rol
  references: { table: "rols", field: "rol_id" },
})
*Note: this just add the constraint to the database, you should already 
have a table and you must define or init your models to sequelize by apart.
```

If you are working with migrations using the sequelize-cli you could:

```
async up(queryInterface, Sequelize){
  await queryInterface.createTable("tableName", {
    //Your attributes here...
  })
  await queryInterface.addContraint("tableName", {
    //Your code goes here...
  })
}
```

If you know a way to add a custom name for the foreign key through the model please let me know.